# AS3: Finding the child object you are clicking on

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a menu MovieClip that has its buttons inside of it. I have the menu with a MousEvent.CLICK and trying to figure a way to register what you are clicking on. Hopefully I'm being efficient about this... Thanks!

```
private function menu_CLICK(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        //this is where I need help on
        switch (????)
        {
            case "books" :
                showSection("books")
                break;
            case "music" :
                showSection("music")
                break;
            default :

        }
    }

    private function showSection(section:String)
    {
        switch (section)
        {
            case "books" :
                trace("books");
                break;
            case "music" :
                trace("music");
                break;
            default :

        }
    }
```

Comment: have a look at 'target', 'currentTarget' for mouse events and 'getObjectsUnderPoint()' ...e.g. private function menu_CLICK(e:MouseEvent):void{   trace(e.currentTarget.name);   }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add event listeners to the each of the Button objects, instead of just one to the menu MovieClip.

You can get the object instance you are clicking on using `e.target`.  Then you either have to compare against members, for example: `if (e.target == books)`, if your menu button is named *books*, or against the stage name: `if (e.target.name == "books")`, or against any custom property you add to the button.

Comment: I'm trying to find the children of the menu you click on. Sorry if I wasn't specific enough.

Comment: It seems I was already a bit too far ahead. I think I'm getting it now - I have edited the answer for you.

Comment: I thought there was a more efficient way to target each child object you click on by using only one event listener

Comment: MouseEvent.CLICK bubbles, that is, moves up in the display list.  If you don't intercept it in between, a single listener on the parent MovieClip should actually be enough.

Answer (score 0):

How about just giving each nested clip an ID?

```
var sections:Array = ['books', 'music', 'other1', 'other2', 'other3']

private function assignClips(){
    // lets say you have 5 buttons/clips inside of your holder movieclip, each named clip0, clip1, etc
    for (var i=0; i<sections.length; i++){
        var mc = holder.getChildByName('clip'+i)
        mc.id = i
        mc.addEventListener.MouseEvent.CLICK, menu_CLICK, false, 0, true)
    }
}

private function menu_CLICK(e:MouseEvent):void
    var id = e.currentTarget.id
    var val = sections[id]
    showSection(val)
}   

private function showSection(section:String){
    trace(section)
}
```